# Spacing between two groups of footnotes

Tags: spacing, manyfoot

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[marginal,multiple]{footmisc}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[symbol]
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[arabic]
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnoteB[1]{%
\oldfootnote{\hspace{1mm}#1}}

\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsum.\footnoteA[*]{*\hspace{2mm} Lorem Ipsum.} Lorem Ipsum.\footnoteA[$^\ast$]{$\ast$\hspace{2mm} Lorem Ipsum.} Lorem Ipsum.\footnoteB{  Lorem Ipsum.} Lorem Ipsum.\footnoteB{  Lorem Ipsum.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am unable to reduce the space between the two sets of footnotes.
Could somebody help me with that? I appreciate it in advance.

Comment: If you want to display code, use the triple backquote on a line by itself, otherwise the code is printed inline and the rendering is wrong. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated it a bit. Now the post is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this hasn't other effects. I remove the `\vskip` from the command that typesets the set of footnotes. I don't think that `manyfoot` provides an interface for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[marginal,multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[fnsymbol]
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[arabic]

\setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\MFL@joinrule{\MFL@skip\MFL@currule}{\MFL@currule}{}{}
\makeatother

\NewCommandCopy\oldfootnoteB\footnoteB
\renewcommand\footnoteB[1]{\oldfootnoteB{\hspace{1mm}#1}}

\textheight=5cm

\begin{document}

Lorem Ipsum.\footnoteA{Lorem Ipsum.} 
Lorem Ipsum.\footnoteA{Lorem Ipsum.} 
Lorem Ipsum.\footnoteB{Lorem Ipsum.} 
Lorem Ipsum.\footnoteB{Lorem Ipsum.}

\end{document}
```

The setting of `\textwidth` is just to make a smaller picture.

Note that you should use `fnsymbol` and not `symbol` for `\footnoteA`.

[image]

Comment: It works. I like this solution. Thank you so much!!